# When upgrade springboot from 2.7.2 to 3.1.2, we met below errors

Tags: java, flyway

After ./gradlew build, met such error
`initializationError FAILED org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException at ParameterResolutionUtils.java:159 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:143 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at ConstructorResolver.java:800 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at ConstructorResolver.java:800 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at ConstructorResolver.java:659 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException at SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError at FlywayAutoConfiguration.java:221`

Have tried different Flyway version, still not work.
Expect after taking ./gradlew build, no errors appeared.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 'implementation "org.flywaydb:flyway-mysql:$flywayVersion" in build.gradle
will solve